# How to remove xap file on uninstallation of sandboxed solution

Tags: sandbox-solution, delete

I have built a simple Silverlight control and a WebPart to go with it. 
This is my first SharePoint project and I was very confused most of the time (I.e. I am a Sharepoint noob)  :-)

The Silverlight Control and the webPart live in a sandboxed solution. After deletion of this solution both are still available in Sharepoint. I gathered this is normal...

I found one how-to on removing files which were provisioned (can't remember the url) but this solution didn't work - I think that was due to the fact that the solution was intended for full-trust-solutions whereas I am using a sandboxed solution.

Any good hint on how I would remove the files of the solution upon deletion of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward. 
You must be deploying the XAP file to a particular list or library and then the Silverlight Web Part must be accessing that XAP file from there correct?

You can add a Feature Receiver to your Feature and then put your deletion code in the `FeatureDeactivating` method of a Feature Receiver.

Just remember that after your XAP file is stored in a list or library, it is just another list item. So you can write code similar to this:

```
SPList list = currentWeb.Lists["Your List Name"];
foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
   if(item.Title == "Your XAP file Name")
   {
     item.Delete()
   }
}
```

(This code is not at all performance optimized. Just used for giving example.)

**UPDATE:**
If you have deployed your XAP file to a folder, try this code in your Feature Deactivation method:

```
SPFile file = currentWeb.GetFile("MySilverlightWebPart/MyControl.xap");
file.Delete();
```

Comment: Did I mention I'm a Sharepoint-Noob ;-) I have an Elements.xml that deploys my xap into a folder like `<File Path="MySilverlightControl\MyControl.xap" Url="MySilverlightWebPart/MyControl.xap" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />`. Does this create a list (or is what I call folder actually a list?)

Comment: check out the update to my answer.